# Need help in understanding a rails active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have two models

Customer and Transaction

```
 Customer
     has_many :transactions

 Transaction
     belongs_to :customer
```

Now I need all the customers having

- more than 1 transaction in last 30 days
- exactly 1 transaction in last 30 days

Comment: Hi Mohit What do you mean? You want to limit the number of transactions that a customer can create to 1?

Comment: @blawzoo no. I want to find out those customers who have only 1 transaction in last 30 days.

Comment: Also I need to find out those customers who have more than 1 transactions in last 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on ScottJShea's answer, I'd use some scopes

```
 scope :one_recent_transaction, :conditions => lambda {
   includes(:transactions).where("transactions.date > ?", DateTime.now - 30.days).group("customer.id").having("COUNT(transactions.id) = 1")
 }

 scope :many_recent_transactions, :conditions => lambda {
   includes(:transactions).where("transactions.date > ?", DateTime.now - 30.days).group("customer.id").having("COUNT(transactions.id) > 1")
 }
```

Then use them like this

```
one_transaction = Customer.one_recent_transaction
many_transactions = Customer.many_recent_transactions
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`HAVING`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having) clause. I suggest (I am guessing a bit not knowing your model exactly):

```
@exactly_one = Customer.where("transaction_date between ? and >", Date.now, Date.now - 30).group("customer.id").having("count(transaction.id) = 1")

@exactly_one = Customer.where("transaction_date between ? and >", Date.now, Date.now - 30).group("customer.id").having("count(transaction.id) > 1")
```